# Having trouble linking to an external CSS file for a signup form inside of Wix

Tags: javascript, html, css

sorry if I'm asking an easy question here.

Scenario - I'm not a developer, but a SMB client I have (everyone wants everything done for free...) had to use one of the generic signup forms from MailChimp after stupid Wix removed the integration it had with MailChimp - basically, in order to push everyone into using their paid product. Here's where the signup form is: https://www.innichkachef.com/

Problem - the form code styling looks like this:

#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
    /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */

I have created a new CSS sheet on Github here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mthompsontpm/signupstylesheetinnichka/main/stylesheet.css

However, whenever I put the new href in the form, it doesn't carry over the styling requested.  It basically becomes unstyled completely.  I am literally swapping the html out like this:

I've also tried it with the https: part, but still no go.

Why is this not working? TIA, and sorry for not knowing what is probably a super easy answer.

Comment: Not sure why they removed my second part of the code, but here's what the swapped out html looks like: <link href="//raw.githubusercontent.com/mthompsontpm/signupstylesheetinnichka/main/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
 /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>

Comment: Welcome @mthompson! I am a little bit confuse with this statement : "new href in the form" . Can you give us a snippet on how you are trying to apply the styling to the form.

Comment: Hi Henry, I'm not sure why StackOverflow removed the code I had in there, but to boil it down.  Original code: <link href="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> and the only thing I tried to do was replace it with the css document I posted on GitHub (see comment above).

Does this help?

Comment: Why are you creating a cdn for github? Is the cdn link from mailchimp not working for you `<link href="cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`? Github isn't built for cdn because it will reveal the css as plain text.

Comment: Not trying to use a CDN at all. Trying to create a CSS document so I can change how the form looks, as the original form is kind of bland in appearance.  Being the free version, I do not have a lot of options, but tried to see about creating a new CSS document to link to so I could change the form's appearance.....but it just doesn't seem to be working.